# Proving continuity of the limit function of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(k^3 x)}{2^k}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(k^3 x)}{2^k}$.

Prove that the limit function is continuous.

I'm confused on what a limit function is...?

Comment: You surely have some ideas on this. Please share.

Comment: Is this a power series? Because it's not in its typical form if yes?

Comment: No, power series look like $\sum a_nx^n.$ Hint: There is a useful test for uniform convergence of series due to Weierstrass.

Comment: Should i consider the Weierstrass M-Test for uniform convergence?

Comment: Hint: It converges `normally`.

Comment: @Bernard i'm not sure how that helps me?

Comment: Normal convergence implies uniform convergence.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$0\le \left|\dfrac{\sin(k^3x)}{2^k}\right|\le \dfrac 1{2^k}.$

Comment: Right, that works for the first part, in using the M-test, which is what I had, correct?

Comment: Yes. I think it's better to mention normal convergence. B.t.w., the limit function here is the sum of the series, as a function of $x$.